# Using AudioUnitSetParameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

First, i know there were some questions here about this topic before this one, unfortunately none of them brought me any luck.

So what i'm trying to do, is create an audio player with some effect, the main one is "reverb", for that i'm using this method:

```
 AudioUnitSetParameter(_reverb.audioUnit, kReverb2Param_DryWetMix, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0,  100.f, 0);
```

The problem is, when i'm trying to use ether parameters of the  reverb unit except kReverb2Param_DryWetMix , such as:

```
kReverb2Param_Gain                          

kReverb2Param_MinDelayTime                  

kReverb2Param_MaxDelayTime                      

kReverb2Param_DecayTimeAt0Hz                    

kReverb2Param_DecayTimeAtNyquist                

kReverb2Param_RandomizeReflections
```

There isn't seem to be any change in the sound!

Any help here who'd be much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Is your audio queue setup,correctly, so is the refurb unit in the queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it what my bad, the thing is, there is no real sound difference as long as the  "kReverb2Param_DryWetMix" is not on. meaning the 5th parameter is different then 0.0